# Can I get bridge section using calculateRoute method from Here Routing API?

Tags: here-api

Can I get bridge section using `calculateRoute` method from Here Routing API? What request parameters should I use, and what response part to look?

Comment: What do you mean by bridge section. Can you give an example route with bridge section and explain?

Comment: Denmark, route E20, the segment of the route E20 is a bridge: "18 km long bridge across the Great Belt (Storebælt) links together the eastern and western parts of Denmark."

Answer (score 0):

You can get the road geometry(in your case, to find if the road is on a bridge) by adding "attributes=ROAD_GEOM_FCn(BRIDGE)" attribute in Fleet Telematics Routing API. Below is an example route on E20. Hope this helps!

```
http://cre.cit.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?app_id=xxxx&app_code=xxxx&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&driver_cost=10&waypoint0=55.308989,10.805059&waypoint1=55.368920,11.288338&attributes=ROAD_GEOM_FCn(BRIDGE)
```

Comment: Please, tell me, do you plan to add "bridge" flag to the Route Link Attributes? For example, to get: {"linkId": "+783445069", "length": 108, "flags": ["tollroad", "motorway", "bridge"], "roadNumber": "A2", "roadName": ""}

Comment: Now I'm using https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_id=&app_code=&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!52.4162,9.6687&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!55.4544,11.5569&mode=car;fastest;traffic:disabled&representation=linkPaging&routeAttributes=none,wp,sm,sc,lg,ri&legAttributes=none,wp,li,le,tt,sm&linkAttributes=none,fl,le,rn,ro,sh   and it is work's fine, return flags are: tollroads, tunnels, etc., and no bridges.